# failed to connect to the ESPoddle server due to IO Exception in my Android Programming

Tags: java, android, ios, eclipse

**This is my service.java**

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.Process;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TheService extends Service {
private Looper mServiceLooper;
private CommunicationHandler mServiceHandler;

private int mId = 0;
public static final int CONNECT = 67;
public static final int CREATE_MEETING = 3;
public static final int CHECK_OPEN = 4;
public static final int SUBMIT_RESPONSE = 5;
public static final int CHECK_RESPONSES = 6;
public static final int CLOSE_MEETING = 7;
public static final int CHECK_CLOSED = 8;

public void onCreate() {
    HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("TheServiceWorkerThread",
            Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
    thread.start();
    mServiceLooper = thread.getLooper();

    mServiceHandler = new CommunicationHandler(mServiceLooper);

    Log.d("TheService", "Service Created");
}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Message msg = mServiceHandler.obtainMessage();

    msg.what = intent.getExtras().getInt("what");
    Log.d("TheService", "msg what = " + msg.what);
    msg.setData(intent.getBundleExtra("arguments"));
    // boolean result=mServiceHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    mServiceHandler.sendMessage(msg);

    // Log.d("TheService","result = "+result);

    return START_STICKY;
}

/*
 * onBind has to be defined, it is a hook method in the abstract class
 * service. If it is not defined the class remains abstract.
 */
public android.os.IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    return null;
}

/*
 * The rest of the program is the inner class CommunicationHandler
 * 
 * The CommunicationHandler is the Handler for the service. It is      
 defined as
 * an inner class in order to use some of the variables of the Service
 * class. The Service method onStartCommand that gets called when an
 * Activity starts the service uses the method sendMessage(msg) with a 
msg
 * built from the data in the intent. The message is received by the 
method
 * handleMessage. This method uses TCP sockets to communicate via the
 * network.
 */

private final class CommunicationHandler extends Handler {

    private Scanner in;
    private PrintWriter out;
    private Socket socket;
    private String phone;
    private String uid;

    public CommunicationHandler(Looper looper) {

        super(looper);

    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        Log.d("TheService", "Handle Message Called with msg.what ="
                + msg.what);
        switch (msg.what) {

        case CONNECT:
            connectToServer(msg);
            break;
        case CREATE_MEETING:
            createMeeting(msg);
            break;
        case CHECK_OPEN:
            checkOpen(msg);
            break;
        case SUBMIT_RESPONSE:
            Log.d("TheService", "About to call submitResponse.");
            submitResponse(msg);
            break;
        case CHECK_RESPONSES:
            Log.d("TheService", "About to fetch Responses.");
            checkResponses(msg);
            break;
        case CLOSE_MEETING:
            Log.d("TheService", "About to close meeting.");
            closeMeeting(msg);
            break;
        case CHECK_CLOSED:
            Log.d("TheService", "About to check closed meetings.");
            checkClosedMeetings(msg);
            break;

        default:
            // super.handleMessage(msg);
            Log.d("TheService", "Returned" + msg.what);

        }

    }

    private void connectToServer(Message msg) {

        String serverIP = msg.getData().getString("host");
        int port = msg.getData().getInt("port");
        phone = msg.getData().getString("phone");
        uid = msg.getData().getString("uid");

        Log.d("TheService_ConnectToServer", "User ID=" + uid);
        boolean isConnected = false;
        for (int numberOfAttempts = 0; numberOfAttempts < 3;  
         numberOfAttempts++) {
            try {
                // Establish a connection with the server
                socket = new Socket();

                SocketAddress sockaddr = new 
       InetSocketAddress(serverIP,
                        port);
                socket.connect(sockaddr, 3000);

                //in = new Scanner(new BufferedInputStream(
                //      socket.getInputStream()));

                BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new 
     InputStreamReader(
                        socket.getInputStream()));

                out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

                out.println(uid);
                String connectAck="";
                connectAck = buf.readLine();

                Log.d("TheService", connectAck);

                if (connectAck
                        .equals(("<Accepted connection from " + uid +  
     "/>"))) {
                    sendNotification("Connected!", "Tap me for 
    actions!",
                            ActionSelectActivity.class,
                            ActionSelectActivity.Send_Action, null);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
    "Connected!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    isConnected = true;
                    break;
                }
            } catch (java.net.UnknownHostException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unknown 
     host",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("TheService", "UnKnow Exception");
                // stopSelf();
            } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "IOException",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("TheService", "UnKnow Exception");
                // stopSelf();
            } finally {

                if (!isConnected) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            "Connection Failed on Attemp No. = "
                                    + (numberOfAttempts + 1),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(3000); // wait 1 second before 
    next

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        if (!isConnected) { // 3 attempts and still failed
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Failed to connect! Service will terminate",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void createMeeting(Message msg) {
        String meetingID = msg.getData().getString("meetingID");
        String timeSlot1 = msg.getData().getString("timeSlot1");
        String timeSlot2 = msg.getData().getString("timeSlot2");
        String timeSlot3 = msg.getData().getString("timeSlot3");
        String part1 = msg.getData().getString("part1");
        String part2 = msg.getData().getString("part2");
        String part3 = msg.getData().getString("part3");

        String msgToSend = "<OpenMeeting>" + "<MeetingId " + "\""
                + meetingID + "\"" + "/>" + " <Message text = " + "\""
                + "Please select a time for the coming meeting." + 
          "\""
                + "/>" + "<time = " + "\"" + timeSlot1 + "\"" + "/>"
                + "<time = " + "\"" + timeSlot2 + "\"" + "/>" + "<time 
  = "
                + "\"" + timeSlot3 + "\"" + "/>"
                + "<Participant numberOfParticipant =" + "\"" + "3>"
                + "<name = " + "\"" + part1 + "\"" + "/>" + "<name = "
                + "\"" + part2 + "\"" + "/>" + "<name = " + "\"" +  
    part3
                + "\"" + "/>" + "</Participant>" + "<OpenMeeting/>";

        out.println(msgToSend);
        String createAck = in.nextLine();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), createAck,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    private void checkOpen(Message msg) {
        Log.d("TheService", "Check Open Meeting");
        String msgToSend = "<CheckOpenMeeting/>";
        out.println(msgToSend);
        String checkOpenAck = "";
        int noOfMeetings=0;
        try {
            BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new 
   InputStreamReader(
                    socket.getInputStream()));

            while (  buf.ready()) {
                checkOpenAck= buf.readLine();
                if (checkOpenAck==null) return;
                int iMeetingIDTag = checkOpenAck.indexOf("<MeetingId    
  ");
                int i1 = checkOpenAck.indexOf("\"", iMeetingIDTag + 
  1);
                int i2 = checkOpenAck.indexOf("\"", i1 + 1);
                String meetingID = checkOpenAck.substring(i1 + 1, i2);
                int iSlot1Tag = checkOpenAck.indexOf("<time = ", i2);
                int i3 = checkOpenAck.indexOf("\"", iSlot1Tag + 1);
                int i4 = checkOpenAck.indexOf("\"", i3 + 1);
                String slot1 = checkOpenAck.substring(i3 + 1, i4);
                int iSlot2Tag = checkOpenAck.indexOf("<time = ", i4);
                int i5 = checkOpenAck.indexOf("\"", iSlot2Tag + 1);
                int i6 = checkOpenAck.indexOf("\"", i5 + 1);
                String slot2 = checkOpenAck.substring(i5 + 1, i6);
                int iSlot3Tag = checkOpenAck.indexOf("<time = ", i6);
                int i7 = checkOpenAck.indexOf("\"", iSlot3Tag + 1);
                int i8 = checkOpenAck.indexOf("\"", i7 + 1);
                String slot3 = checkOpenAck.substring(i7 + 1, i8);

                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putString("meetingID", meetingID);
                b.putString("slot1", slot1);
                b.putString("slot2", slot2);
                b.putString("slot3", slot3);

                sendNotification("You are invited to " + meetingID,
                        "Tap to respond!", OpenMeetingActivity.class,
                        OpenMeetingActivity.Respond_Action, b);
                noOfMeetings+=1;
                Log.d("TheService", checkOpenAck);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (noOfMeetings==0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "0 Open 
     meetings, or server not ready. Try Again 
            Later",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private void submitResponse(Message msg) {
        Log.d("TheService", "About to submit a response.");
        String meetingID = msg.getData().getString("meetingID");
        String timeSlot = msg.getData().getString("selectedTimeSlot");

        String msgToSend = "<SelectedTime>" + "<MeetingId " + "\""
                + meetingID + "\"" + "/>" + "<time = " + "\"" + 
      timeSlot
                + "\"" + "/>" + "</SelectedTime>";

        Log.d("TheService", "Response = " + msgToSend);
        out.println(msgToSend);
        String createAck = in.nextLine();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), createAck,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    private void checkResponses(Message msg) {

        String meetingID = msg.getData().getString("meetingID");
        Log.d("The Service", "Fetching Responses for Meeting ID = "
                + meetingID);
        String msgToSend = "<CheckMeetingRespond><MeetingId " + "\""
                + meetingID + "\"" + "/><CheckMeetingRespond/>";
        out.println(msgToSend);
        String checkResponse = "";
        Bundle b=new Bundle();
        int responseCount=0;
        try {
            BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new 
      InputStreamReader(
                    socket.getInputStream()));

            while (buf.ready() ) {
                checkResponse=buf.readLine();

                int iPartName = checkResponse.indexOf("<name ");
                int i1 = checkResponse.indexOf("\"", iPartName + 1);
                int i2 = checkResponse.indexOf("\"", i1 + 1);
                String partName = checkResponse.substring(i1 + 1, i2);
                int iSelectedTime = checkResponse.indexOf("<time = ", 
       i2);
                int i3 = checkResponse.indexOf("\"", iSelectedTime + 
       1);
                int i4 = checkResponse.indexOf("\"", i3 + 1);
                String selectedTime = checkResponse.substring(i3 + 1, 
        i4);


                //if (checkResponse==null) return;
                if (checkResponse.contains("NumberOfRespond ")) break;
                responseCount+=1;
                b.putString("Response:"+responseCount+".By:", 
         partName);

b.putString("Response:"+responseCount+".SelectedTime:", selectedTime);
                Log.d("TheService", "Name = "
                        + partName + "-> Time = "+selectedTime);

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (responseCount==0){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "0 Response 
avaiable, or server not ready. Try Again 
      Later",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        b.putInt("NoOfReponses", responseCount);
        b.putString("MeetingID", meetingID);
        sendNotification(responseCount+ " Responses fetched ",
                "Tap to close meeting!", CloseMeetingActivity.class,
                CloseMeetingActivity.CLOSE_MEETING, b);
    }

    private void closeMeeting(Message msg) {
        Log.d("TheService", "About to close meeting.");
        String meetingID = msg.getData().getString("meetingID");
        String timeSlot = msg.getData().getString("selectedTimeSlot");

        String msgToSend = "<CloseMeeting>" + "<MeetingId " + "\""
                + meetingID + "\"" + "/>" + "<SelectedTime time = " + 
   "\"" + timeSlot
                + "\"" + "/>" + "</CloseMeeting>";

        Log.d("TheService", "Response = " + msgToSend);
        out.println(msgToSend);
        String createAck = in.nextLine();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), createAck,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    private void checkClosedMeetings (Message msg){

        Log.d("TheService", "Check Closed Meeting");
        String msgToSend = "<CheckClosedMeeting/>";
        out.println(msgToSend);
        String checkOpenAck = "";
        Bundle meetingsIDBundle = new Bundle();

        try {
            BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new 
     InputStreamReader(
                    socket.getInputStream()));

            while (  buf.ready()) {
                checkOpenAck= buf.readLine();
                if (checkOpenAck==null) return;
                int iMeetingIDTag = checkOpenAck.indexOf("<MeetingId 
    ");
                int i1 = checkOpenAck.indexOf("\"", iMeetingIDTag + 
    1);
                int i2 = checkOpenAck.indexOf("\"", i1 + 1);
                String meetingID = checkOpenAck.substring(i1 + 1, i2);
                int iSlotTag = checkOpenAck.indexOf("<SelectedTime 
       time = ", i2);
                int i3 = checkOpenAck.indexOf("\"", iSlotTag + 1);
                int i4 = checkOpenAck.indexOf("\"", i3 + 1);
                String slot = checkOpenAck.substring(i3 + 1, i4);



                if (!meetingsIDBundle.containsKey(meetingID)){ //The 
  bundle is used to avoid duplicate notification of the same meeting

                meetingsIDBundle.putString(meetingID, meetingID);
                sendNotification("Meeting " + meetingID + " is 
  closed",
                        "Selected time is"+slot, 
 ActionSelectActivity.class,
                        ActionSelectActivity.Send_Action, null);
                }

                Log.d("TheService", checkOpenAck);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
    /*
     * This method prepares a notification that calls an Activity.
     */

    private void sendNotification(String t, String s, Class target,
            String action, Bundle dataBundle) {
        // String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = 
(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher; // icon from resources
        mId += 1;
        Context context = getApplicationContext(); // application 
 Context

        CharSequence tickerText = "Message from server";
        CharSequence contentTitle = t;
        CharSequence contentText = s;

        NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new 
 NotificationCompat.Builder(
                getApplicationContext()).setSmallIcon(icon)
                .setContentTitle(contentTitle).setTicker(tickerText)
                .setContentText(contentText).setAutoCancel(true);

        /* the notification will call an activity with this intent */
        // Intent notifyIntent = new
        // Intent(ActionSelectActivity.Send_Action);
        Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(action);
        // added so that each intent is unique. i.e. to avoid 
  overwriting
        // previous data in"putExtra"
        notifyIntent.setData((Uri.parse("custom://"
                + System.currentTimeMillis())));
        notifyIntent.setClass(context, target);
        notifyIntent.putExtra("arguments", dataBundle);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = 
    PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                        | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL);

        // notification. |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        /* complete configuration and notify */
        notification.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
        mNotificationManager.notify(mId, notification.build());

    }
   }
   }
```

**This is my Main Activity program**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is 
present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void ConnectClickHandler(View v){
    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Just Clicked 
 Connect!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    EditText etServerIP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET_ServerIP);
    EditText etUID =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET_UID);
    String ip=etServerIP.getText().toString();  //hold server IP
    String uid=etUID.getText().toString(); // hold User ID
    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ip + "  
 "+uid,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    final Intent intent = new Intent(this, TheService.class);
    intent.putExtra("what", TheService.CONNECT);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putInt("port",4444);
    b.putString("host",ip);
    b.putString("uid", uid);
    intent.putExtra("arguments",b);
    Log.d("MainActivity","About to start the service");
    Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this , "Trying to connect...", 
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    startService(intent);
    //Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this  , "Connected...", 
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    finish();
 }
```

mainly i want to connect to ESPoodle server using port 4444 but whenever i try to connect it gives me a failed connection which i'm unable to resolve